# Dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and now I need to install Windows 7 along with it.

I only have one sda1 partition on my HDD and it occupies the whole space, so how can I dual boot my system?

[image: screenshot of Gparted showing 461 GiB ext4 root, 3.9 GiB swap inside an extended partition]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make partition on disk to install windows on it using gparted.
2. Now install windows on the newly created partition. Once installed, you will not have an option to boot into ubuntu.
3. To fix this, you have to use a live ubuntu usb and fix grub to show both ubuntu with windows os.

Comment: Partition must be primary NTFS partition with boot flag. Usually works with gparted, but some have reported they had to redo with the Windows installer. Use gparted to shrink ext4 partition, and be sure to follow general rule of Linux tools for Linux & Windows tools for Windows.